# MongoDB: поиск вложенных документов в массиве

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

### Ситуация

У меня есть коллекция вида:

```
[
  {
    ttl: [
      {
        lng: 'ru',
        txt: 'Ru Text Example'
      },
      {
        lng: 'en',
        txt: 'En Text Example'
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    ttl: [
      {
        lng: 'es',
        txt: 'Es Text Example'
      },
      {
        lng: 'en',
        txt: 'En Text Example'
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

### Вопрос

Как произвести поиск по всем полям `txt` в этой коллекции (вне зависимости от поля `lng`)? При этом количество документов в поле `ttl` может быть любым. Например, при поиске строки "En Text Example" должны вернуться два документа из этой коллекции.

Comment: Здесь, на SO, не ставят задачи, а просят совета решить их. За вас из никто не будет решать.

Comment: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/text-search/